# Suggestions for reading data from excel in .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, import-from-excel

I need to read in data from excel files in my c# winforms app. Any recommendations on good components for this? I've used syncfusion some years ago and that seemed to do the trick.

There'll be a bunch of header lines I need to skip (so a straight ADO approach won't work easily) and then a table of data with standard columns but variable number of rows.

I'll be pumping the data into SQL Server db once it's read, but probably need to do validation etc on it before that.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately we opted for [Syncfusion's XLSIO](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/reporting-edition/xlsio) which works well.

Thanks for the other suggestions too.

Answer (score 2):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) will do it.

You can see ASP.NET samples with C# and VB source [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it out.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 1):

[Using ASPOSE Tools](http://www.aspose.com/categories/file-format-components/aspose.cells-for-.net-and-java/default.aspx)

[Using ADO.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934)

Do you need graphic support?

Comment: don't need graphic support - i assume you mean reading in images?

Answer (score 1):

Im using the ComponentOne XLS component right now. It is pretty stable and does it job. Im using it for data integration too.

I also wanted to do some xls reports, however the API does not support the full excel stack (not even launching an excel instance) so i had to go over Mirosoft.Office.Interop

Answer (score 1):

One of alternatives: [MS Office Wrapper for .NET](http://www.codeplex.com/msofficefornet)

Answer (score 1):

you can use LINQ to XML also,
see the link below...

[Video Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/learn/linq-videos/video-218.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

We're currently using [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp).  It has some nice features including a tool for reading a spreadsheet and generating the necessary C# (or VB or Delphi) code to generate that sheet using their toolkit  -- it makes designing a sheet a snap.  The licensing wasn't expensive (site license for developers, redistribution free).

The only thing against it is that XLSX (Excel 2007 native format) compatibility is "real soon now".

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
// Connection String to Excel Workbook
string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"";

OleDbDataAdapter oleDbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", excelConnectionString);

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

oleDbDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
```

Also see "SqlBulkCopy"

Comment: Once you have the dataset (ie all rows in the Excel worksheet)
Rows can be skipped/ignored/rejected/logged through counts (if files are known/consistent) and through validation on each row/column.

Comment: I agree that ADO is a great way to get data from Excel in some situations but I've found it to be a pain in some cases, eg if the data isn't very sanitized. Also requires annoying client changes to ensure data typing is done well. So in this case I want a component that provides a nicer API.

Answer (score 0):

Read this blog post on Reading and Writing Excel Spreadsheets.

[Reading and Writing Excel Spreadsheets](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/26/2973.aspx)

Comment: This suggests a straight ADO approach but I'd prefer a component to help with some of the complexities.